# how to show a button after onclick on image in android

Tags: android, image, button

I have a griview.In that gridview i clicked one of the image.After onclick on that image then show a button(Download).after onclick that button(Download) then onclicked image will be downloaded .so please tell me how to show a button after onclick on any image in gridview.

Thank you.

Best Regards.

Comment: You question is very incoherent. Can you ask it more clearly?

Comment: i edited my question in above

Answer (score 0):

this is the code  it working my machine

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    }
});
```